# How to stylize border of require input box when it alerts

Tags: html, css

See the picture below:

[image]

I want to stylize the red box-shadow and for example change the color of it.

**EDIT:** 
When we use a code like this:

```
 <input type="text" name="example" required>
```

if user click on submit button without completing the required box, it alerts! I wanna change default shadow color.

Comment: "when it alerts" where is the code to make it *alert* ..? :/

Comment: I userd the required attribute! see my edit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
input:invalid {  
    box-shadow:0 0 0px #f00;
}
```

will override the shadow.

Note, however, that styles entered here will style any required boxes before the form has been submitted. As such, I suspect you may need to run a javascript on submit which adds a class to the form, so that the styles only appear post-submit.  For example, make it so that submitting the form adds a class called "submittedform" to the form and then add the styles.

```
.submittedform input:invalid {  
    box-shadow:0 0 0px #f00;
}
```

(There may be a html5 way of doing this, but I don't think there is)

Comment: Note also that html5 client-side validation hasn't been around long.  Javascript validation may still be more sensible depending on how many users you get on older browsers.

Comment: I found [an article](http://html5doctor.com/css3-pseudo-classes-and-html5-forms/) that also mentions adding the class and created [a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/stephen61/aYA43/) demonstrating it.

Answer (score 3):

You should use `box-shadow` CSS property for this :

```
input { box-shadow: 0 0 10px red; }
```

#### [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Sftzn/2/)

Comment: Oh I know that but I want to stylize an input box when it alerts not generaly!

Comment: @Amir : What do you mean by alerts? Show your js then, I can't guess everything you are dreaming about. Do you mean when is is focused?

Comment: lol. IMHO i don't think it's a good practice to encourage such questions... in my opinion, this shows no effort...

Comment: By "when it alerts" Amir means when the browser's HTML5 validation prevents the form submit because the `required` field is empty and highlights the field. No javascript is needed to do this; it part of HTML5 form validation.